# How do I properly install GTK+ on Ubuntu 12.04 Precise?

Tags: python, gtk, ubuntu-12.04, openstreetmap

**The Issue:** I am trying to install GTK+ on Ubuntu 12.04, and while it seems to have installed, each time I attempt to run a python program which uses 'import gtk', I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gps_slip_map.py", line 3, in 
    import gtk
ImportError: No module named gtk
```

The python code for gps_slip_map.py can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/2refnvMY)

**What I've Done So Far:** There are a few dependancies that I needed here: osm-gps-map and gtk+.
In order to download osm-gps-map I used the command, from [here](http://nzjrs.github.com/osm-gps-map/):

```
sudo apt-get install libosmgpsmap-dev python-osmgpsmap
```

In order to download gtk+ I used the command, from [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=403647), post #9 by 'p0c4r1':

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-core-devel build-essential libgtk2.0-dev libgtk2.0-doc devhelp
```

I have installed both of these and when I attempt to again, I receive confirmation in the form of this message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libosmgpsmap-dev is already the newest version.
python-osmgpsmap is already the newest version.
gnome-core-devel is already the newest version.
build-essential is already the newest version.
libgtk2.0-dev is already the newest version.
libgtk2.0-doc is already the newest version.
devhelp is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  language-pack-zh-hans yaml-cpp language-pack-kde-en libwxgtk2.6-0 language-pack-kde-zh-hans language-pack-kde-en-base libwxbase2.6-0 python-central language-pack-zh-hans-base
  language-pack-kde-zh-hans-base
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 165 not upgraded.
```

A friend who is working with me on this project was able to simply install Ubuntu 12.04 Precise and use the command to install osm-gps-map. This worked for him and the software ran without throwing an ImportError. I did this same thing, and it is not working for me.

**Conclusion: *Is someone able to help me figure out how to fix this ImportError?***

**Update 1:** It seems as though the PYHTONPATH is correct.... the command 'echo $PYTHONPATH' shows:

> PYTHONPATH: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/

But, when I use the command 'ls /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/', it seems as though **there is NO GTK** listed anywhere.

```
dateutil                       ipython-0.14.dev-py2.7.egg-info  _mlt.so       numpy-1.6.2-py2.7.egg-info   pytz                 wx.pth
freenect-0.0.0-py2.7.egg-info  matplotlib                       mlt_wrap.o    pylab.py                     README               wxPython_common-2.8.12.1-py2.7.egg-info
freenect.so                    matplotlib-1.3.x-py2.7.egg-info  mpl_toolkits  pylab.pyc                    serial               wxversion.py
IPython                        mlt.py                           numpy         pyserial-2.6-py2.7.egg-info  wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode  wxversion.pyc
```

To me it seems like this is the issue, but I have no idea how to go about manually adding the proper file here so that I can import gtk. **Does anyone have any idea how to do this?**

Answer (score 2):

Yes - it sounds like you also need the Python binding for GTK+

For example:

- apt-get install python-gtk python-glade2

It's also possible that you have a configuration mismatch.  Look at the advice in this link:

- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1674508

Comment: It looks like I currently have 'python-gtk2' and 'python-glade2' installed. As far as the configuration match is concerned, I know I have python 2.7.3 installed... Other than that I am having trouble finding a thread of info that I can use in the thread.

Comment: Q: Where did gps_slip_map.py come from?  Is it possible that maybe it's looking for an old, obsolete version of GTK?

Comment: gps_slip_map.py is a custom file that is a part of a project I am working on. the line that calls gtk is literally just 'import gtk'. Would it be helpful for you to check out the code?

Comment: Sorry - I don't see anything "obviously wrong".  Per [this link](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq01.010.htp), please make sure you're running *only* Python 2.7, and you don't have some other version inadvertently installed as well.  Also, try re-emerge, per [this link](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-765959-start-0.html): http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Python_maintenance